# angularJs custom directive not working with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJs. I am writing my custom angular directive which contains a template of some html content. When I use the template with the below code it works fine.

```
demoApp.directive('demoCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:'true',
    template: "<h1>This is from the custom directive..</h1>"
  };
```

});

But when I replace the template with templateUrl pointing to a html inside a partial I am getting error.

```
demoApp.directive('demoCarousel', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace:'true',
    templateUrl: "/partials/carousel.html"
 };
```

});

The javascript error is something like:

> Error: [$compile:tplrt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$compile/tplrt?p0=glassCarousel&p1=%2Fpartials%2Fcarousel.html

Please let me know where I am going wrong and what the correct way to use the templateUrl

Note: I am using only pure html code inside the carousel.html file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24compile/tplrt?p0=glassCarousel&p1=/partials/carousel.html) sais: `Template for directive 'glassCarousel' must have exactly one root element. /partials/carousel.html`

this means that you have something like this in your template:

```
<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>
```

It is not allowed, you should have one root element:

```
<div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: +1 A must if you using an external file, as an alternative to the ui-bootstrap examples that use templateUrl  that calls code in the "index.html"